# FreeRTOS lpc3250 porting

Tags: arm, freertos

I try porting FreeRTOS on LPC3250, but my port works unstable. I tryed use port by Thomas Kindler, it's avaliable [here](https://interactive.freertos.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/210027446-LPC32xx-ARM9-with-FPU-support-using-GCC) and I catch the same behavior with my port. I try to execute following:

```
void task1(void *) {
  BOOL_8 blink1 = TRUE;
  TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
  const TickType_t xFrequency = 500;
  xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
  while(true) {
      if (blink1)
          cpld_set_bits(ECPLDLeds, CPLD_LED_1);
      else
          cpld_clear_bits(ECPLDLeds, CPLD_LED_1);
      blink1 = (~blink1) & 0x1;
      //      for (volatile int i=0; i < 8000000; ++i);
      //      vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
      vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, xFrequency );
   }
}

void task2(void *) {
  BOOL_8 blink2 = FALSE;
  TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
  const TickType_t xFrequency = 500;
  xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
  while(true) {
    if (blink2)
        cpld_set_bits(ECPLDLeds, CPLD_LED_2);
    else
        cpld_clear_bits(ECPLDLeds, CPLD_LED_2);
    blink2 = (~blink2) & 0x1;
    //      for (volatile int i=0; i < 8000000; ++i);
    //      vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, xFrequency );
  }
}

extern "C" int c_entry()
{
  bool blink5 = true;
  isens_board_init();

BaseType_t result = xTaskCreate(
    task1,
    "task1",
    configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
    NULL,
    tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1,
    &task1Handle
);
(void)result;

BaseType_t result2 = xTaskCreate(
    task2,
    "task2",
    configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
    NULL,
    tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1,
    &task2Handle
);
(void)result2;

vTaskStartScheduler();

while(true) {
    if (blink5)
        cpld_set_bits(ECPLDLeds, CPLD_LED_0);
    else
        cpld_clear_bits(ECPLDLeds, CPLD_LED_0);
    blink5 = !blink5;
    for (volatile int i=0; i < 16000000; ++i);
}
return 0;
}
```

If I run tasks delayed by for() cycle - it works correctly. If I run tasks delayed by vTaskDelay or vTaskDelayUntil functions - it works bad. I see folowing behavior: two times it switch well, but then task1's led stops. After few secconds (5-10) lights again, then turns off again after random period. Task2's led blinks stable with 500ms period.

Maybe it is effect of uncorrect startups? Or bad usage of mmu (I use mmu cause using cash)? Must I use FreeRTOS with mmu supported?

[Startups avaliable here.](https://github.com/GeorgeBatuchenko/test)

Thank you.